# Jsoup error casting node.element to element.Element

Tags: java, casting, jsoup

I am trying to iterate through two Elements in java using Jsoup, however, I am getting a runtime exception error. It appears that I cannot cast the type of nodes.Element to element.Element.

I would really appreciate your help, thanks.

Code:

```
    Elements elements1 =  doc.select("title"); 
    Elements elements2 =  doc.select("link"); 

    Iterator<org.jsoup.nodes.Element> iter1 = elements1.iterator();
    Iterator<org.jsoup.nodes.Element> iter2 = elements2.iterator();

        while (iter1.hasNext() && iter2.hasNext()) {
            Element element1 = (Element) iter1.next();
            System.out.print(element1);
            Element element2 = (Element) iter2.next();
            System.out.print(element2);

        }
```

Runtime Error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jsoup.nodes.Element cannot be cast to javax.lang.model.element.Element
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce the Exception. Could you post your imports?

Comment: Jsoup Element has quite extensive set of methods providing access to many w3c.dom.Element equivalent functionality, why not try those. Unless ofcourse you are trying to loose couple with JSoup

Comment: @Ironluca Could you possibly show me how to do this or give me a link to a tutorial, thanks.

Comment: What i see is that you are trying to print the element, is there anything specific that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can sum up your code like this:

```
for(org.jsoup.nodes.Element e : doc.select("title, link")) { 
   switch(e.tagName().toLowerCase()) {
       case "title":
       case "link":
          System.out.print(e);
       break;

       default:
          // handle unexpected element...
   }
}
```